# Can I compile come C# dll's with Xamarin and build a custom UI in Android?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono

I have a lot of business logic coded in C#. I don´t know a lot about Xamarin, but as far as I know, you have to use the full framework. What I would like to do is just use Xamarin to compile the business logic into an android DLL and then code the Android app using them. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what code you actually have in your business objects.

Xamarin uses Mono which is open source port of .NET. It then takes the Mono code and compiles that to Android. Any 3rd party libraries you have referenced or use probably will not work. You would need to find a Mono library (still may be incompatible on Android) or an Android library that has the functionality you need and re-code those parts.

Xamarin does have the ability (with paid version) that let you to reference Java Jars and work with them in your C# Android project. This is most beneficial when the .NET/Mono library you were using does not work in Android, but an equivalent Android or Java library does.

Again, it is really up to whether or not any of the classes you use outside of your own have been implemented in Mono and then implemented in the Android versions of it.